# Bootstrap columns in mobile version

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to make a website, but it's something is wrong.

I want to make 2 rows and 3 columns and when the screen changes to mobile, I want it to be 3 rows and 2 columns.

Desktop

```
|A|   |B|   |C| 
|D|   |E|   |F|
```

Mobile

```
|A|  |B|
|C|  |D|
|E|  |F|
```

I used the code below to do it, but the images don't stay like I want it to.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">Content</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">Content</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">Content</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">Content</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">Content</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">Content</div>
</div>
```

The images stay like this

```
|A| |B|
    |C|
|D| |E|
|F|
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have run into this problem before.  The issue has been that my content is different heights.  Because Bootstrap uses floats to arrange it's columns your column C cannot float all the way to the left if your column A is taller than column B.

I have included a link to a codepen so you can see it in action.  The top two rows are exactly your code above while the bottom two rows show a div with a different height than the other divs.

http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/PGRQYK

The solution for you will be to set the height of your divs to the max height for all your content.  Something like

```
.maxHeightDiv {
    height: 200px;
}
```

You'll probably have to set heights for different window widths.  It can be a little annoying but this is a caveat of the bootstrap float system.

Answer (score 11):

4 columns on desktop and 2 columns on mobile:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3 col-6 m-auto"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-6 m-auto"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-6 m-auto"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-6 m-auto"></div>
</div>
```

May need to add class fluid to image object to keep the image responsive within div.

Comment: This should be the answer. Simple and Elegant.

Comment: Yes! Simple and Elegant. And what a great thing to know.

Answer (score 2):

I am using **[Stacked to Horizontal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#stacked-to-horizontal)** & [**Mix and Match**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mix-and-match) in Boostrap.

### **1. Stacked to Horizontal**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">col-sm-8</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">col-sm-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
  <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
  <div class="col-sm">col-sm</div>
</div>
```

**Desktop View:**
[image]
**Mobile View:**

[image]

### **2. Mix and Match**

```
<!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-8">.col-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">.col-6</div>
  <div class="col-6">.col-6</div>
</div>
```

**Desktop View:**
[image]

**Mobile View:**

[image]

**Code from:**

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mix-and-match
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#stacked-to-horizontal

Comment: Best legal answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is old maybe it helps some of you.

My way is more code than probably necessary but I couldn't came up with a bootstrap grid system solution that provides different column and row changes in combination with screen width changes.

So lets start:

- Switching to `.scss` and implement bootstrap responsive functions
- Include a parent div which acts as a view toggle container for your bootstrap gird system
- Usage of `display: none !important` and `display: inline !important` for the divs
- A hint, set the width of the image class to `max-widht: 100%;`, it will force the images to take as much place as they can without exceeding its parent width; unless you want different unique sizes of course

`.scss`: (check your bootstrap css [version](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) )

```
$stageZero: 540px;
$stageOneLower: 719px;
$stageOneHigher: 720px;
$stageTwoLower: 959px;
$stageTwoHigher: 960px;
$stageThree: 1140px;

@mixin stage00 {
  @media (max-width: $stageZero) { @content; }
}

@mixin stage01 {
  @media (min-width:$stageOneLower) and (max-width:$stageOneHigher)  { @content; }
}

@mixin stage02 {
  @media (min-width:$stageTwoLower) and (max-width:$stageTwoHigher) { @content; }
}

@mixin stage03 {
  @media (min-width: $stageThree) { @content; }
}
.mobileViewToggle {
    @include stage00 {display: inline !important;}
    @include stage01 {display: none !important;}
    @include stage02 {display: none !important;}
    @include stage03 {display: none !important;}
}
.desktopViewToggle {
    @include stage00 {display: none !important;}
    @include stage01 {display: inline !important;}
    @include stage02 {display: inline !important;}
    @include stage03 {display: inline !important;}
}
```

`.html`:

```
<div class="mobileViewToggle">
    < Bootstrap Grid Code with xs prefix, e.g. col-xs-4>
</div>

<div class="desktopViewToggle">
    < Bootstrap Grid Code with sm prefix, e.g. col-sm-6>
</div>
```

Comment: Seemed like a good solution,but for some reason at a certain width both my divs appeared at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below class as shown...

1. `col-xs-2` -  will be two columns only on xs devices-(mobile)
2. `col-md-3` - will be 3 columns on all devices other the mobile

`<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-3">Content</div>
    ....
    </div>`

You cannot change the rows however without using js.
Moreover,on mobile,does it really matters... ?

Comment: This is wrong.  col-xs-2 means it takes up 2 of 12 spaces on xs screens.  The code @Fernanda is currently using (col-xs-6) is correct for 2 columns on mobile.

Comment: col-xs-2 - will be two columns only on xs devices-(mobile)...does this means something else...i said the same thing!!